# How to index with ELKI - OPTICS clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, elki, optics-algorithm

I'm an ELKI beginner, and I've been using it to cluster around 10K lat-lon points from a .csv file. Once I get my settings correct, I'd like to scale up to 1MM points.

I'm using the OPTICSXi algorithm with LngLatDistanceFunction

I keep reading about "enabling R*-tree index with STR bulk loading" in order to see vast improvements in performance. The tutorials haven't helped me much.

Any tips on how I can implement this feature?

Comment: Use the `-db.index` parameter to add an index. use the bulk load option, to configure bulk loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested parameters for using a spatial R* index on 2 dimensional data are:

```
-db.index tree.spatial.rstarvariants.rstar.RStarTreeFactory
-pagefile.pagesize 512
-spatial.bulkstrategy SortTileRecursiveBulkSplit
```

For higher dimensional data, larger page sizes are necessary. A page size of 512-1024 bytes seems to be the sweet spot for 2 dimensional data, but it does depend on your data, too.

To discretize clusters, you can use the Xi extraction:

```
-algorithm clustering.optics.OPTICSXi -opticsxi.xi 0.005
```

To benefit from index acceleration with OPTICS, choose epsilon as small as possible for your application. The parameter is in *meters* with all the earth models in ELKI.

```
-opticsxi.algorithm OPTICSHeap
-algorithm.distancefunction geo.LatLngDistanceFunction
-optics.epsilon 2000.0 -optics.minpts 10
```

uses 2 km distances maximum.

Make sure to distinguish `latitude,longitude` and `longitude,latitude`. Both orders are used, and you *need* to use the right distance function:

```
geo.LatLngDistanceFunction
geo.LngLatDistanceFunction
```

Comment: Thank you! For the benefit of those who follow, here's what I'm executing which seems to work pretty well on my specific dataset:


java -jar <path> cli -algorithm clustering.optics.OPTICSXi -dbc.in <path> -db.index tree.spatial.rstarvariants.rstar.RStarTreeFactory -pagefile.pagesize 1024 -spatial.bulkstrategy SortTileRecursiveBulkSplit -opticsxi.xi 0.006 -optics.minpts 5 -algorithm.distancefunction geo.LngLatDistanceFunction -geo.model WGS84SpheroidEarthModel -opticsxi.algorithm OPTICSHeap -resulthandler ResultWriter -out <path>